# ArcMap 10.1 - UTM Zone Display Mismatch

Tags: arcgis-10.1, coordinates

I've recently noticed that the UTM zone displayed in the Identify box and the "Goto XY" box display a different UTM zone than the one I'm in.  I'm working in WGS84 NAD83, Zone 13N but when I use the Identify tool and look at the location of the point it shows the location as '13S X,Y'.  Also, if I type in a set of coordinates manually using the "Go To XY" tool, I type it in as 13N X Y, and hit enter, after it flashes the location the zone I had input is changed to 13S.

*Can someone explain why the zone is being displayed as 13S and not 13N?*

I'm assuming this is one of those weird geometric things that I never picked up in school.  Hopefully someone can enlighten me!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The S references the latitude band, not if it's North or South.  See the Wikipedia page at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system.

Comment: To expand a little, the UTM coordinate system definitions used in ArcGIS use N and S to signify northern or southern hemisphere zones (different false northing values). The 'single point' tools like Go To XY and Identify display a UTM string with a latitude band letter instead. If you switch to MGRS or USNG, their first letter is the latitude band as well.